# Docker won't startup - "Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS"

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Whenever I try to open Docker Desktop I get the error saying "Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS".

So far I tried:

- Turning off Hyper-V function through control panel.
- Using commands bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off and bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto.
- Unistalling VirtualBox (latest version as of posting this).
- And of course I have the virtualization in BIOS enabled.

All of this to no avail.

What's more weird is that I used Docker the day before and there was no issue whatsoever with it.

I'm working on Windows 10 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Hypervisor capabilities within Windows need to be enabled for Docker to work. This can start with BIOS settings to enable Hypervisor capabilities (BIOS/System dependent). Then it can depend on the version of Windows you have exactly how to enable Hypervisor stuff (often labeled "Hyper-V").

There was a "Personal" version of Windows I was saddled with on a laptop which required numerous changes, including new registry keys, for a lot of common development tools and network tools to work.

So it's important to enable hypervisor capabilities from the BIOS through to Windows - A quick synopsis of enabling the hypervisor stuff in Windows is:

- Open Settings Click on Apps.
- Click the Optional features tab
- Under the “Related settings” section, click the “More Windows features” setting
- Check the Hyper-V option to enable the virtual machine platform on Windows 11

This isn't a solution per se, but a diagnostic tool I've used in the past (albeit infrequently): DISM, which might provide some insight on the root of the problem:
https://pinter.org/archives/8168

I've given the link to ensure credit to the originator of the idea.

I do not have administrator credentials for the system I am working on, otherwise I'd provide a DISM walkthrough here.